# C++ circular inclusion -> forward declare class definition withouth header inclusion

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is a solution to circular inclusion by forward declaring i higher-level-function in a lower level function as shown in the example below:
What i would like to do (This is my actual question) is like in C-Style rather than including the header of a module to access a function of it, definining the function itself in the current file without the need to include the module header.

Architecture Example:

```
APPLICATION (highest layer)
    |
    v
MIDDLEWARE (layer in between)
    |
    v
OPERATING SYSTEM (lowest layer)
```

Code Example:

This example gives the following 2 errors:

- a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions
- incomplete type Application used in nested name specifier

```
// OS.hpp -------------------------------------------------
// !!!! HERE I WILL NOT INCLUDE APPLICATION.HPP !!!!
// I JUST USE THE APPLICATION DEFINITION TO ACCESS THE 
// STATIC FUNCTION
extern class Application;

class OS {
public:
    OS() {}
    ~OS() {}
    int getInfo() { return Application::get(); }
}
// Middleware.hpp -----------------------------------------
#include "OS.hpp"

class Middleware {
    OS os;
public:
    Middleware() {}
    ~Middleware() {}
    void doSomething() { int a = os.getInfo(); }
}
// Application.hpp ----------------------------------------
#include "Middleware.hpp"

class Application {
    Middleware mw;
public:
    Application() {}
    ~Application() {}
    void run() { mw.doSomething(); }
    static int get() { return 0; } // !!!! this function (static) i would like to access from OS
}

// main.cpp -----------------------------------------------
#include "Application.hpp"

int main() {
    Application app;
    app.run();
}
```

Comment: You use `Application::get()` in the definition of `getInfo`, currently in OS.hpp, therefore you depend on the definition of the type in the header itself. Have you considered having an OS.cpp with the definition of `getInfo`, so that your OS.hpp would stop having that dependency?

Comment: No, the definition of `getInfo` is clearly known to `OS`.

Comment: You're wrong. The definition of `OS::getInfo` is currently known to the definition of `OS`: you put it directly within its `{ }` block. Now, the definition of `Application::get` is not currently known to `OS`; in fact, it doesn't even know the declaration of that name! That's what you're currently missing. To define `OS::getInfo`, you need the definition of `Application`, and the declaration of `Application::get` (so it knows what the name means)

Comment: By the way, is an "`extern`" forward declaration really a thing your compiler accepts? If I recall correctly, it's only used for function and object declarations

Comment: @KABoissonneault "This example gives the following 2 errors: - a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions"

Comment: @KABoissonneault Yes this is my question. Extern refers to functions and variables (objects). But what is the equivalent to tell the compiler to ignore the Application and tell him to trust that AT LINK TIME the Application object will be known and linkable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you put `get` in the scope of `Application`, the definition of `Application` is currently a requirement you cannot work around. 
If you don't need the private members of `Application` to call `get`, you could consider having an externally-linked namespace-scope function `int application_get();`, which can be declared in `OS.hpp` without issue

```
// OS.hpp
int application_get();

class OS {
public:
    OS() {}
    ~OS() {}
    int getInfo() { return application_get(); }
};

// Application.hpp
class Application { 
    // ...
public:
    Application() {}
    ~Application() {}
    void run() { mw.doSomething(); }
    static int get() { return 0; }
};
inline int application_get() { return Application::get(); }
```

Let me state that I have huge doubts about such a design, from a software architecture point of view, but you asked for a tool around your problem and here's one. I will trust you will make the decision that's best for you

Comment: hehe thanks. yeah i just wanna see what options are available. i will try to avoid such designs in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some cpp files to make this work and include the method bodies in those files to avoid the problem you've stated.

For instance change OS to be this:

```
class OS {
public:
    OS() {}
    ~OS() {}
    int getInfo();
};
```

Then declare the body of `getInfo` in a cpp:

```
OS::getInfo() { return Application::get(); }
```

and include Application.h and OS.h at the top of that cpp.

Comment: thank you, i know this would work. 
but i would keep a strict policy that forbits to include higher layers in lower layers.

typically what i can do is to wrap the static class function in a global function and declare the wrapper function extern in OS. but i was hoping to get a more direct way

Comment: @Lukas So you are not allowed to _include_ higher layers in lower layers but you are allowed to _call_ higher layers from lower layers? This is somewhat strange

Comment: No it is not that far off.. think of it as callback in for of a trade off.. layered, keeps the architecture alive but still able to do the same a circular inclusion does..